# Spring batch : .bat file

Tags: spring-boot, oracle11g, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler

Can anyone help me please, I did the spring batch coding but just the job is executed, I want to execute a .bat file but it didn't execute the .bat file.
How to execute a file .bat in spring batch? I want to run my .bat file in the script field in angular.

I'm working with spring batch and angular.

please, help me.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

private static final String QUERY_FIND_TACHES =
       "select * from hr.task";

@Bean
 public ItemReader<Task> taskItemReader() {
   JdbcCursorItemReader<Task> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

   databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
   databaseReader.setSql(QUERY_FIND_TACHES);
   databaseReader.setRowMapper(new TaskRowMapper());

   return databaseReader;
   }

@Bean
public TaskItemProcessor processor() {
    return new TaskItemProcessor();
}


@Bean
public ItemWriter<Task> itemWriter(TaskRepository taskRepository) {
    return new ItemWriter<Task>() {
        private int task = 0;

        @Override
        public void write(List<? extends Task> items) throws Exception {
            task += items.size();

            System.out.println("written " + task + " brackets");

        }
    };
}

 @Bean
 public Step step1(ItemReader<Task> taskItemReader, ItemWriter<Task> itemWriter) {
 return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
.<Task, Task> chunk(10)
.reader(taskItemReader)
.processor(processor())
.writer(itemWriter)
.build();
}

 @Bean
 public Job testJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
  return jobBuilderFactory.get("testJob")
.incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
//.listener(listener)
.flow(step1)
.end()
.build();
```

}

and code taskRowMapper

```
public class TaskRowMapper implements RowMapper<Task>{

@Override
public Task mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

    Task task = new Task();

    task.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    task.setNom_job(rs.getString("nom_job"));
    task.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
    task.setScript(rs.getString("script"));
    task.setDate_execution(rs.getDate("date_execution"));

    return task;
} 

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `How to execute a file .bat in spring batch? I want to run my .bat file in the script field.`? Do you want to run a .bat script from within a tasklet (like a SystemCommandTasklet) in the job or do you want to start the job from .bat file?

Comment: I want to implement a .bat file from Angular and Spring that it executes
I want to do like  windows scheduling tasks  when I create a task